# how can i access images from server in my android mobile app if images restricted for direct web access by .htaccess

Tags: android, jquery, .htaccess, jquery-mobile, mobile

We are creating Android Mobile application with Intel app framework.We are uploading content(images,pdf,videos) on our server by jQuery. 
On server by security resign we want to restrict direct web access through .htaccess. But it also restrictive in mobile application.

so my question is how we can display image in mobile app even if it is restricted for direct access.

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Rohini

Comment: One way to do it is by providing services on the backend to deliver those images. This way, you should avoid that restriction. This is not a real answer, as it to depends on you have control over the services.

Comment: plz explain with example

Comment: create a service that accepts an ID or the filename of a certain image, and make that service return the file asked. this way you can still have the protection from direct access and also have a way to get files, being authenticated.